# laying out html elements without using inline styles

Tags: html, css

I'm coming from an iOS background and having trouble laying out elements in HTML and using CSS.  I want to create something as "simple" as this:

[image]

I want to be able to split the screen in separate divs but have all the fieldsets align with each other.  (They are fieldsets but I didn't draw them in my primitive mockup.  I also didn't put anything in the third box but there's more stuff in there).

But here are some of my questions:

Box 1 questions:
I basically have `style="display:block;"` in all my elements.  If I have an overarching div as `style=display:block`, I don't get the same effect.  Is there a better way to do that?

Box 2 general question:
I ended up hardcoding all my styles to sort of achieve the image shown.  It doesn't seem very usable or scalable.  Any general principals I should start with?

```
<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; float:left; width:25%">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>First fieldset</legend>
        <div style="display:block;">field 1
            <input type="text" style="display:block;" />
        </div>
        <div style="display:block;">field 2
            <select style="display:block;">
                <option>field 2 options</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style="display:block;">field 3
            <input type="text" style="display:block;" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; width:33%">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Second fieldset</legend>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div class="one-half" style="display:inline-block; float:left;">
            <input type="radio" name="scoops" />Single
            <div style="display: block">Radio 1</div>
            <div style="display: inline">Radio 2
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: block">
                <input type="checkbox" />Radio 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-half" style="display:inline-block;">
            <input type="radio" name="scoops" />Double
            <div style="display: block">Blah 1</div>
            <div style="display: inline">Blah 2
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: block">
                <input type="checkbox" />Blah 3</div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Step 1: Wait 5 years; Step 2: Use flexbox; Step 3: Profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title says it all, don't use inline styles or it will quickly become a mess. Create an external stylesheet to hold all CSS, and style groups of elements targeted with CSS selectors.

Start by simplifying the structure. You have three columns, so three divs. It's a good idea to wrap them too:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="col1"></div>
    <div id="col2"></div>
    <div id="col3"></div>
</div>
```

So you want them side-by-side. Floating them or using `inline-block` elements are two common techniques to achieve that. You tried to use both at the same time, choose one. I'll give an example for floating:

```css
#wrapper { overflow: hidden; } /* clear the floats at the end, 
                                  so the wrapper extends down  */
#col1, #col2, #col3 { float: left; }
#col1 { width: 25%; }
#col2 { width: 33%; }
```

You also don't need a div wrapping every field, and you don't have to manually make divs `block` (they are blocks by default, and fieldsets are too). Use labels and make them blocks too:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>First fieldset</legend>
    <label for="fld1">field 1</label>
    <input id="fld1" type="text">

    <label for="fld2">field 2</label>
    <select id="fld2">
        <option>field 2 options</option>
    </select>

    <label for="fld3">field 3</label>
    <input id="fld3" type="text">
</fieldset>
```

And make them all blocks:

```css
label, input, select { display: block; }
```

I hope this gives you a general idea you can apply to the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what CSS classes are for : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

For starters here are classes for your left and right sections:

```
.left {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}
.right {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:33%;
}
```

In use: http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/BM6Fp/#base

```
<div class="left">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>First fieldset</legend>
        <div style="display:block;">field 1
            <input type="text" style="display:block;" />
        </div>
        <div style="display:block;">field 2
            <select style="display:block;">
                <option>field 2 options</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style="display:block;">field 3
            <input type="text" style="display:block;" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Second fieldset</legend>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div class="one-half" style="display:inline-block; float:left;">
            <input type="radio" name="scoops" />Single
            <div style="display: block">Radio 1</div>
            <div style="display: inline">Radio 2
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: block">
                <input type="checkbox" />Radio 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-half" style="display:inline-block;">
            <input type="radio" name="scoops" />Double
            <div style="display: block">Blah 1</div>
            <div style="display: inline">Blah 2
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: block">
                <input type="checkbox" />Blah 3</div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```